# How to make class objects observable in MobX?

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-state-tree

I've a class as:

```
class Field{

  constructor(name) {
    this.name= name
    this.otherAttr = null
  }

  changeName(newName) {
    this.name = newName
  }
}


const f = new Field("Charanjit")
f.setName("Singh") // It shoukd reflect in observer 

f.name = "Rahul" // It should also reflect in observer
```

How to make `f` object observable such that any changes in `f`'s attributes, update the observer components.

Currently, I'm getting error: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1932 if I use:

```
@observable(f)
>>> It shows Error: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/1932
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at MobX documentation, It would be probably a good approach doing something like that:

```
import { observable, action, decorate } from "mobx";

class Field {
    name = '';
    otherAttr = null;

    changeName(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

decorate(Field, {
    name: observable,
    otherAttr: observable,
    changeName: action
})
```

Mark properties as observables with the decorate utility will do what are you looking for.
Please go through the docs: https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html